# How to display Special characteres in xslt href attribute

Tags: xml, xslt, attributes, href, special-characters

i want to display a link in xslt table that contient frensh special charactres:
the link is dynamic composed from : `https://website.com/sites/the_name_of_attachment_in_xml`

the xslt link:

```
<a><xsl:attribute name="href">https://website.com/sites/<xsl:value-of select="Attachments" disable-output-escaping="yes"/></xsl:attribute>
 <xsl:value-of select="Attachments" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
</a>
```

the html result is:

```
<a href="https://website.com/sites/ExampleName.pdf">ExampleName.pdf</a>
```

the issue is when the introduced name contient special charactere
for example : pr`é`sentation,
the link will be:

```
<a href="https://website.com/sites/Pr&amp;#233;sentation.pdf">Présentation.pdf</a>
```

the `"é"` charactere in the link is replaced by `"&amp;#233;"`

i used `disable-output-escaping="yes` to display correct charactere it worked just for
<xsl:value-of select="Attachments" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
but didn't work in href attribute, i see other solution that tell to change in xslt code the

`<xsl:output method="html" />` to  `<xsl:output method="xhtml" />` , but it didn't work form me i get error.

the result i want is:

```
<a href="https://website.com/sites/Présentation.pdf">Présentation.pdf</a>
```

How can i display the correcte link with special charactere using xslt?

this is xslt code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="html" />
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <table id="tableRepeat" border="1" width="100%" style="border-collapse:collapse;color:black;font-size:100%;font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif;">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <td>Attachments</td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <xsl:for-each select="//Items/Item">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                        <!-- this is how i display my link  -->    
                        <a>
                        <xsl:attribute name="href">https://website.com/sites/<xsl:value-of select="Attachments" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
                        </xsl:attribute>
                        <xsl:value-of select="Attachments" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
                        </a>
                        <!-- end: this is how i display my link  -->
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

because i didn't get the right url, it shows me page not found with this

```
equestUrl=https://website.com/sites/training/Lists/.../pr%26
```

`pr%26` it stop here

and when i inspecte  i got this:
[image]

Comment: I don't understand how you are getting `&amp;#233;`. That would indicate that `&#233;` was somehow double escaped, and when I executed a test, I get URLEncoded values in my `@href` with `%C3%A9` for the `é`, which is what you would expect: https://www.urlencoder.org

Comment: i read some where that &amp;#233; that xml is iso code for é; and %26#233; is html iso code for é, have u any suggestion to resolve this issue

Comment: Well, that is a different story. That’s just bad XML input. The & should not be escaped when part of an entity.

Comment: this is the xml :

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RepeaterData>
    <Version />
    <Items>
        <Item>
            <Title type="System.String">test</Title>
            <Attachments type="System.String">pr&amp;#233;df.pdf</Attachments>
        </Item>
    </Items>
</RepeaterData>

Comment: i found here: https://ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm ; and here : https://www.degraeve.com/reference/urlencoding.php; that "&" symbol has html name: &amp; and has html number: &#38; and "é" symbol has html name: &eaucute; and has html number: &#233; and the symbol "&" her Url Encoded Character is: %26.